# Compiling multiple C++ files using make

Tags: c++, makefile

I am attempting to use Makefile for the first time. Is it possible to compile 2 different c++ programs into 2 executables using one Makefile?

Here is what I've done so far but it will only compile the first one.

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall

series : ./problem1/series.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o series ./problem1/series.cpp

gn : ./problem1/gn.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o gn ./problem1/gn.cpp
```

EDIT:

How can I stop it from compiling every time (unless I modify the code)?

```
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall

all : q1_series q1_gn q1_series_new_initial

q1_series : ./problem1/series.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o ./executables/q1_series ./problem1/series.cpp

q1_gn : ./problem1/gn.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o ./executables/q1_gn ./problem1/gn.cpp

q1_series_new_initial : ./problem1/series1.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) -o ./executables/q1_series_new_initial ./problem1/series1.cpp

    echo "Question 1 created in ./executables"
```

Comment: GNU make (the standard make) is extremely powerful and flexible. I suggest reading the manual, or a good book. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. You make a "Fake" target, that is dependent on both other programs

```
all_programs : series gn
```

Answer (score 1):

By default when you run `make` make runs the rules for the first target it sees. In your case that would be the `series` target.

You can manually run any other target(s) you want by specifying them on the command line `make gn` or `make gn series` for example.

If you want make to default to building more than the first target you give it a first target that does what you want.

The general name for this target is `all`. So you would add `all: series gn` *before* the current target entries.

You will likely also want to mark that target as `.PHONY: all` so that in case some `all` file ever managed to be created running `make all` would still work the way you expect (and not attempt to check the modification time of the `all` file against its prerequisites, etc.).